# Publishing both jar and sources jar to Artifactory from Gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "admin"
                password = "password"
            }
            name = "maven-main-cache"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'codenarc'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

version="0.0.2"
group = "mylib"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    add buildscript.repositories.getByName("maven-main-cache")
    maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/myapp-snapshots"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'myorg-snapshots'
            username = "admin"
            password = "password"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

task dist(type: Zip, dependsOn: build) {
    classifier = 'buildreport'

    from('build/test-results') {
        include '*.xml'
        into 'tests'
    }

    from('build/reports/codenarc') {
        into 'reports'
    }

    from('build/docs') {
        into 'api'
    }

    from(sourcesJar) {
        into 'source'
    }

    from('build/libs') {
        exclude '*-sources.jar'
        into 'bin'
    }
}
```

Based on this current setup:

- To build my JAR I have to run `gradle clean build groovydoc sourcesJar dist` and then
- To publish to Artifactory, I have to run a second command of `gradle artifactoryPublish`

Two things I'm looking to change here:

1. `gradle artifactoryPublish` only publishes my built JAR and a dynamically-created POM to Artifactory. I'd like it to also publish the sources JAR that my build is creating. **How?**; and
2. Ideally I'd like to be able to do all of the above by just invoking `gradle publish` instead of having to run the 2 commands sequentially. **Is this possible? If so, how?**

Answer (score 19):

When it comes to publishing source you need to modify your script in the following way:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact (sourcesJar) { 
                classifier = 'sources'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes to a single command what you need to do is to define dependencies between tasks. Unfortunately I can't try the script so it may be redundant but should do the job:

```
artifactoryPublish.dependsOn('clean', 'build', 'groovydoc', 'sourcesJar', 'dist')
publish.dependsOn(artifactoryPublish)
```

Comment: Adding 'clean' as a dependency to `artifactoryPublish` for some odd reason causes everything to build, then clean, then try to publish... this fails obviously because there is now nothing to publish anymore. How can I force 'clean' to happen before everything else?

Comment: A solution (though I don't know if it's the best one) would be to use the following: `compileJava.dependsOn('clean')`

Comment: `artifactoryPublish` might have dependencies defined internally. Will check it on tomorrow.

Comment: Can't find sources for `artifactoryPublish` task, hence I'm unable to investigate the dependencies. What else would like you like me to do? I'd like to get the bounty :)

Comment: It was not the OP that started the bounty. It was I.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that! Nevertheless, thank You very much @agent154!!

Comment: `sourcesJar`,  doesn't that task have to be defined first?

Comment: @AmanuelNega it is defined in the question.

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo, please have a look at the question.